# check arraylist element equals an array

Tags: c#, arrays, arraylist

I am trying to test whether an element equals an array. However, even if `array==arraylist[element]` the value of `repetitive` is still set to false.

Here is my code:

```
bool repetitive = false;
foreach(var element in arraylist)
{
    if (array.Equals(element))
        repetitive = true;
}
return repetitive;
```

Comment: really you're just testing the last item in `arraylist`, you reset `repetitive` with each iteration

Comment: what is array, what are the types of the "elements". What is the goal of this code ?

Comment: int[,] array=new int[8,8];

Comment: Just use `Contains`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to either return true after you have found a duplicate value or do an `or equals`.

Return true method:

```
bool repetitive = false;
foreach(var element in arraylist)
{
    if (array.Equals(element))
        return true;  //<<< This is the difference
    else
        repetitive = false;
}
return repetitive;
```

or using bit-wise or-equals

```
bool repetitive = false;
foreach(var element in arraylist)
{
    if (array.Equals(element))
        repetitive |= true;
    else
        repetitive |= false;
}
return repetitive;
```

Comment: what elements are you comparing? Maybe it's comparing memory references and not values?